# Can I make VS Code soft wrap code to prettify/beautify it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, minecraft

I am currently working on datapacks in Minecraft and am looking for a thing that would make my life more enjoyable. Minecraft uses mcfunction files in datapacks. These are basically just Minecraft commands. Now these commands can get very long with a lot of attributes. But as opposed to a 'normal' language, you can not have a new line for things in between brackets.

An example command for spawning a zombie with a lot of attributes:

```
summon zombie ~ ~2 ~ {HasVisualFire:0b,Silent:1b,CustomNameVisible:0b,DeathLootTable:"roguelite:entities/soulfighter",PersistenceRequired:0b,NoAI:0b,Health:80f,Tags:["soulfighter"],Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:armor_stand",Marker:1b,Invisible:1b,Tags:["soulfighter"],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:iron_nugget",Count:1b,tag:{CustomModelData:2}}]}],CustomName:'{"text":"Soul Fighter"}',ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:stone_button",Count:1b,tag:"burner"}],active_effects:[{id:"minecraft:fire_resistance",amplifier:1b,duration:999999,show_particles:0b},{id:"minecraft:invisibility",amplifier:1b,duration:999999,show_particles:0b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.max_health,Base:80},{Name:generic.movement_speed,Base:0.3}]}
```

This all has to be on one line. Except for if you use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to get a long line within screen width in VSCode. Which wraps it the multiple lines without starting a 'new line of code', so to say.

I was wondering if there is an <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> equivalent, for not just wrapping at screen width, but at a specific point in a line. So that I can have a more JSON like look for my commands.

I have already troubleshot a bit, but I get overflown with the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> answer, which isn't what I am looking for.

Edit: Let me exemplify with images.

Current state:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYRHl.png

When pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXDHn.png

You can see that when pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> the code is all on line 4 still but visually below eachother (no code on line 5). This is what I want to achieve manually. So that I may start the cutoff after a specific point and not just screenwidth.

An example of what I want to achieve:
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv5RN.png
This makes the code more readable for myself, and clearer asto what belongs to what.

Comment: I think you're going to need to be more clear about what you want when multiple breaks are desired- where exactly they should be, and what logic decides where they should be. show the desired appearance you want to see given your example input.

Comment: @starball there needs to be no specific logic behind it, I am merely seeking for manually applicable line breaks, after for example a comma. I'd  be able to press some key combination that moves the rest of the line to a new line. Not like enter does, because it reads the code as an actual new line of code(e.g. a command).

Comment: so you actually want to insert a line break into the text? I thought you said that would make the command invalid? inserting a line break after a comma is easy. just use find and replace

Comment: @starball apologies for unclarity, i edited the post to include images, that hopefully lead it to make more sense.

Comment: that's called "soft-wrap" (when no actual line-break is inserted into the text). now I ask you the same question I started with. you need to define logic for how you want the wrapping to happen. why isn't the builtin soft wrapping satisfactory to you? what determines how the soft wrapping that you want to have should happen?

Comment: @starball Added one more foto with an example of what i aim to achieve with the soft wrap, no real logic iguess? but more of a more readable command for myself

Comment: by the way, not sure if it came across clearly, but when I say "logic", I mean in the sense of the word as "[business logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic)" / behaviour-specification- not "reasoning / rationale".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with VS Code's builtin features, but you could probably write an extension to insert linebreaks so things display pretty during "development", and then strip linebreaks for testing/"release". Or you could build something like [`plievone.vscode-template-literal-editor`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plievone.vscode-template-literal-editor), which creates a virtual document for editing with linebreaks inserted and a formatter implementation, and that synchronizes it with an "actual" file where there are no linebreaks.